Exchange of Saturn and venus in Libra
My Dob 25 jan 2002 1:24 AM saturn in Taurus with moon and Venus in capricon also i have libra asc. what are results of this exchange

I am vote to close this question, as you need to do your own research and find your own astrologer for that. astrology is something that has too many variables and interpretations - you just cannot have one single answer for that specific question.
